# How to permanently stop Samsung Galaxy S5 from keep connecting to Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5. At my place of employment, Wi-Fi is provided (a free version which isn't locked, and a version which is locked). It keeps connecting to the unlocked Wi-Fi network. I don't want to connect to either. I want to control which networks I connect to and when, whether they are free or not (especially if they are free as I imagine that's how hackers get access to your personal info).

I went into Settings -> Connections -> Advanced and turned off almost everything I could think of, but it still scans for networks and connects to the open free network.

How to stop the phone from automatically connecting to a Wi-Fi network and instead only connect to a Wi-Fi network when prompted by me?

Comment: Did you "forget" the bad network. Afaik you will be asked by the phone at least once before connecting

Answer (score 1):

In the list of wifi networks, you can select the open network, then "forget this network" -- after doing that, the phone won't connect without asking.  As long as you don't give permission, and have "automatically connect to open networks" disabled, the worst it will do is prompt you to connect to this "new network".

Answer (score 0):

Disable the WiFi from the Notification Menu to stop the device from connecting to the WiFi network.

1. Drag down from the top of your device screen, the notification menu and a range of quick action buttons will appear.
2. Assuming your phone is connecting to the WiFi, the 'WiFi' quick button will be a green colour signifying it is enabled. Touch the button once, and wait for it to turn light grey. This means your WiFi is off.
3. Pull up the notification menu, and look at the status bar. There should be no WiFi symbol visible and your phone isn't connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: So that is my problem.  I go through those steps.  But eventually my phone tries to reconnect to WIFI!!!!  I don't want it to even look until I tell it too.

Comment: Under WiFi Advanced, do you have a setting 'Scanning always available'?

Comment: On my Galaxy Note 2, I have a "Connections Optimizer" setting which looks for wi-fi connections you have previously used. This may be the culprit.